# DevExpress Universal Template with Authentication

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, devexpress, wrapper, devextreme

I installed DevExpress Universal cause I need Grid View and Chart for my web. Also I am trying out ASP.NET Core and already started creating a web application with the Microsoft template for ASP.NET Core MVC. My application needs authentication for users and I am using Individual User Accounts which was supplied by the Microsoft Template. Is it possible to integrate DevExpress Library in my project instead of creating a new project with the DevExpress Template? I am planning to use ASP.NET MVC Wrappers from DevExpress, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In previous version there has been an Integrate DevExpress option in the DevExtreme menu but this release "DevExtreme MVC Wrappers" is quite new or could be RC release. It is not so difficult to do it manually, please refer to this article on how to proceed [ASP.NET MVC Wrappers 16.1.6](http://nextgen.guru/post/asp/).

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible. first you need to add devExpress reference in your project before, then you can use a devExpress Templete.